# Filling up a column with a value that satisfy conditions from other columns

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have table like below:

```
con_no     pr_no     flag_1  flag_2
con_002   1000234      1       0
con_002   1000345     -1       0
con_002   1100200      1       1
con_002   1005890      0       0
con_003   1100367      0       0
con_003   1000445      1       1
con_003   1200334     -1       0
con_003   1140567      1       0
```

Now I want another column filled with `pr_no` whose flag_2 = 1 and where flag_1 = 1 within a specific `con_no`. So the resultant table should look like

```
con_no     pr_no     flag_1  flag_2  Parent_pr
con_002   1000234      1       0      1100200 <---This belongs to con_002
con_002   1000345     -1       0      
con_002   1100200      1       1      1100200 <---This belongs to con_002
con_002   1005890      0       0
con_003   1100367      0       0
con_003   1000445      1       1      1000445 <---This belongs to con_003
con_003   1200334     -1       0
con_003   1140567      1       0      1000445 <---This belongs to con_003
```

How to achieve the above using python (pandas) or SQL. Actually this table in a database (postgreSQL). So a SQL Query string will also do.

There is a catch though. Every times a program runs, the `con_no` gets reshuffled. Some `pr_no` may be attached to either a new or an existing (but different `con_no`).

Comment: Use case when in SQL. To do it in Python create a function with an if-else statement call this function through pandas dataframe.

Comment: @AyushKesarwani: Please elaborate with your code snippet. Either in SQL or in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should join the table with itself. If your data are in table named `my_table`, a query like this should work:

```sql
with cte as (
    select con_no, pr_no
       from my_table
      where flag_2 = 1)
select t.con_no, t.pr_no, t.flog_1, t.flog_2, cte.pr_no as parent_pf
  from my_table as t
  left outer join cte on (cte.con_no = t.con_no and t.flag_1 = 1)
```

Comment: 1st part I have understood that you are filtering out the data only with those `pr_no` whose `flag_2`=1. Not quite sure about the second part. Why `'left outer join`?

Comment: `left outer join` is join that add column from the right side (here `cte`) and leave it empty if there is no correspondence. The usual `inner join` would have limited the number of rows to those where the `on` condition would have match (which means all lines in your example where `parent_pr` is null would have not been displayed

Comment: OK. lets assume that every time a program runs, and this `con_no` gets reshuffled. I.e. `pr_number` gets tag to a different `con_no`. What will happen then?

Comment: In this case of course the result will change if you play the query again. If you want to store the results, you need to use either another table, or use pandas dataframes, but it's another story (for instance, as far as you talk about reshuffling data, will you need to store all states? If yes, how willl you distinguish them?

Comment: While `con_no` changes, `pr_no` and their associated flags remain same. So what will happen if I join using `pr_no` instead of `con_no`?

Comment: I have modifIed the OP.

Comment: The query will adapt the result to the new situation: isn't it what you want? Did you try the query? I have to leave for now, I'll be back later on

Comment: I review your update, and of course the parent_pr will change if con_no changes... but the rule is to look within con_no so I do not see how to we could keep a result if you change the way data are grouped.

Comment: by any chance your code will create a column named `parent_pr`, every time the above code is run?

Comment: Yes! I mean, each time the code is run, you will get the 5 columns in the `select (...) from my_table (...)`. But actually you should test by your own

Comment: I have tested and saw that it is creating. This is not the requirement. The requirement is to keep on updated that `parent_pr`. Can you please modify the code accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean? A request reads the database with the current values, if you change the data, the results will change. If you want to keep trace of the results on the previous run, it's another story and you should implement object(s) to save the data accordingly. I do not thing I can go deeper for you as you may know much better than I your project's environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function and conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag_1 = 1
             then max(case when flag_1 = 1 and flag_2 = 1 then pr_no end) over (partition by con_no)
        end) as parent_pr
from t;
```

Actually, Postgres supports the `filter` syntax, so I would write this as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag_1 = 1
             then max(pr_no) filter (where flag_1 = 1 and flag_2 = 1) over (partition by con_no)
        end) as parent_pr
from t;
```

Comment: `pr_no` is a string, not int

Comment: @pythondumb . . . And?  What difference does that make?

Comment: How `max()` would work on string?

Comment: @pythondumb . . . Try it.  It uses whatever the default collation is, which is typically dictionary order.